# Data nao aceita no banco de dados Mysql

Tags: java

Estou com uma duvida pois estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando o *Spring Boot*, tenho minha tabela no banco *MySQL* pronta e funcionando normalmente porem não esta salvando a data aparece este erro no console.

```
Field error in object 'tarefas' on field 'data': rejected value [2017-10-22]; codes [typeMismatch.tarefas.data,typeMismatch.data,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tarefas.data,data]; arguments []; default message [data]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'data'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Column @javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2017-10-22'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
Field error in object 'tarefas' on field 'data_realizacao': rejected value [2017-10-27]; codes [typeMismatch.tarefas.data_realizacao,typeMismatch.data_realizacao,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tarefas.data_realizacao,data_realizacao]; arguments []; default message [data_realizacao]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'data_realizacao'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Column @javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2017-10-27'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
2017-10-23 01:08:44.606  WARN 7596 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'tarefas' on field 'data': rejected value [2017-10-08]; codes [typeMismatch.tarefas.data,typeMismatch.data,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tarefas.data,data]; arguments []; default message [data]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'data'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Column @javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2017-10-08'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
Field error in object 'tarefas' on field 'data_realizacao': rejected value [2017-10-25]; codes [typeMismatch.tarefas.data_realizacao,typeMismatch.data_realizacao,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [tarefas.data_realizacao,data_realizacao]; arguments []; default message [data_realizacao]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'data_realizacao'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Column @javax.persistence.Temporal java.util.Date] for value '2017-10-25'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

Seque aqui a minha classe de persistência

```
/**
     * classe modelo persistencia tarefas
     */
package com.web.Models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tarefas")
public class Tarefas implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5686959667099623912L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="data")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date data;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="data_realizacao")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date data_realizacao;

    public Tarefas() {

    }

    public Tarefas(long id, Date data, String nome, String descricao, Date data_realizacao) {
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.data_realizacao = data_realizacao;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Date getData_realizacao() {
        return data_realizacao;
    }

    public void setData_realizacao(Date data_realizacao) {
        this.data_realizacao = data_realizacao;
    }





}
```

E aqui e o meu formulário *HTML*

```
<h1>Cadastro de Tarefas:</h1>
    <form method="post">
        Data:<input type="date" value="" name="data"/>
        Data Termino:<input type="date" value="" name="data_realizacao"/>
        Descricao:<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="descricao"></textarea>
        Nome:<input type="text" value="" name="nome"/>
        <button type="submit">Salvar</button>

        <h2><a href="/todasTarefas">ver todas as tarefas</a></h2>

    </form>
```

O que pode ser isto pensei que fosse o tipo de data porem na classe de persistência com o banco utilizo o `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`, já pesquisei aqui no site não encontrei ajuda.

Comment: O formato provavelmente que você está usando talvez esteja incorreto. Tente usar assim: `yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s`.

Comment: Sim mais eu mudaria isto no html na minha classe de persisitencia ou no banco?

Comment: Se você não está usando hora somente data, o ideal seria você alterar de TIMESTAMP para DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizei:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

na minha classe.